# Starting out in Android tablet development

Tags: android, tablet

I recently bought a `Motorola XOOM` tablet to develop Android apps on. I'm running into major problems with finding resources to learn from. I know Java. The Android Dev Guide sample codes are almost all dependent on a keyboard or won't run on my `XOOM`. Are there any suggested places to start learning Android development, other than the Android Dev guide?

Answer (score 4):

You will be creating a new avd config to specify the tablet screen size, memory constraints, SDcard size, etc. I believe that most of that can be achieved by just creating a new avd and changing the parameters in avd manager. Although You may also have to create a tablet skin to go with the AVd you created.

Please visit these links.... They breif you right from setting up the vitrual device configuration in eclipse to development of applications for tablets.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_tablet_virtual-device-configuration/

*[2x Links deleted due to spam, 1x Link repeated]*

I hope these links will help you in creating an android app for your beautifull tablet.

Answer (score 1):

To start learning android,First preference goes to Android dev guide and you can  also follow some tutorials ,blogs and e-books.But Dev guide provides the complete android stack.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [MOTODEV](http://developer.motorola.com/). The resources are quite good especially with XOOM development.

Answer (score 1):

Check out O'Reilly eBooks on eCarrel (eReader for developers app).
The app will run on your XOOM just great.
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ambrosoft.searchlib

I also use the XOOM for development and I love it

Answer (score 0):

Answers above are great, here is an addition:

http://p-xr.com