# will android mobile app will work on android tablet?

Tags: android

If I develop app for my mobile phone, is it going to work on android tablet ?

If no, what should I need to develop app for an android tablet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what it is that your app does the answer is yes it will run on a tablet. However if you designed that app for phone sized devices it is likely going to not be the greatest user experience for tablet if you make no changes to it. If you want to support both phone and tablet consider making tablet specific layouts so that at the very least you can make use of the extra screen real-estate.

One of the newer honeycomb features allows the user to choose zoom or stretch mode when using apps designed for phones this alleviates some of the problems but it is still best to design a layout specific for tablets.

Edit: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092829/starting-out-in-android-tablet-development) has some great links to get you started working with tablets.

Comment: What I need to develop app for an android tablet ? Should I just start like regular mobile development and instead of 2.2 etc I should choose 3.0 and go on, right ?

Comment: You can still build for the 2.2 version. It is more a matter of making a separate layout file that is actually designed to use up the extra space a tablet affords. See link in Edit.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean?

If I develop an application targeting Android 2.2, let's say, then that application will work on all Android 2.2+ devices, so 2.3, 3.0, 3.1, and 3.2. However, if you're developing an application solely for Honeycomb/3.0+ tablets, then you should probably make use of the new features in Honeycomb for layout on tablets and such.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to develop an app that should work on both your mobile and the tablet, you should take a look at the [official](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html) dev guide.

However, before getting into that, you should probably learn a bit more about [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) (introduced in 3.0) which will give you a two-pane view on tablets.